# Is it possible to create a custom prototype method on a specific instance of a type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

As you know, an Array's prototype can be modified to give it custom methods.

```
Array.prototype.foo = function () {}
```

But those methods then apply to ALL Arrays anywhere in the entire application.

Is there a way to accomplish something like this:

```
let dArray = [];
dArray.prototype.foo = function () {}
```

With the result being that only the `dArray` instance has that custom method?

Obviously, *this* way will not work, but is there another way to achieve that result?

Comment: _"a custom prototype method on a specific instance"_ is an oxymoron, if you don't want to patch Array just write a function.

Comment: `dArray.prototype` does not make sense. Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) to learn what the `prototype` property is for: it’s a property on _constructors_ whose value gets used as _the prototype_ of its instances. Note that “the prototype” and “the `prototype` property” are not the same concept. If you want a method ony on one instance, just define it directly: `dArray.foo =`…. Of course, note that this isn’t exactly best practice.

Comment: I understand the documentation and the standard.  I am asking of there is a way to accomplish something LIKE this.  And you did.  Thanks.  I didn't think about just attaching a function directly to the specific object.  Seems obvious.  You'd think I would have thought of that.